# Uncaught TypeError: a.setElement is not a function in ext-all.js

Tags: javascript, extjs6

How to fix the following error of `extjs Version: 6.0.0`, that happens in `IE`, `Google Chrome` and `Firefox`. The demo is as the follows:

[image]

Here is the code. If removing the ',locked: true', the issue is gone. What is the right way to add `locked: true`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>extjs 6 demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='https://cdnjs.cat.net/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css' />
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.state.*',
    'Ext.form.*'
]);

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
      storeId: 'store2',
      fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
      groupField: 'name',
       //header: 'Test',
      proxy: {
          type: 'memory',
          reader: {
              type: 'json',
              rootProperty: 'items'
          }
      }
});

store.add([{
      'name': 'Gooooogle',
      "phone": "111-222-3333"
}]);


var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Demo Grid',
    store: store,
    columnLines: true,

    autoHeight: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    width: 515,
    enableColumnMove: false,
    enableDragDrop: false,
    enableHdMenu: true,
    enableColumnHide: false,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Company Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
        ,locked: true
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
        ,locked: true
    }, {
        text: 'Grouping Columns',
        columns: [{
            text: 'Phone 1',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }, {
            text: 'Phone 2',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }, {
            text: 'Phone 3',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your tried code ? people be able to post better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `autoScroll: true`. It's a bug that has been fixed in subsequent versions. There's no need to specify it, since grids scroll as a default.

Also, your code that creates the grid should be wrapped in `Ext.onReady` block.

Note: `scrollable: true` could lead to the same issue as `autoScroll: true`